# Building spring boot project with maven

Tags: eclipse, spring, maven, spring-boot

I'm new in Spring. I follow [this](http://spring.io/guides/gs/serving-web-content/) tutorial, yet I can't make it run. Is it possible to build deployable jar or war file straight from eclipse? If so, how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just go: Run as > Maven install. That will make a `jar` file in a `target` folder.

Comment: Problem is, I get a successful build, but target folder is empty. This is output with suspicious warning.
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO]
[INFO] Total time: 3.000 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2015-11-09T20:24:08+01:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 18M/227M
[INFO]
[WARNING] The requested profile "pom.xml" could not be activated because it does not exist.

Comment: Ermm... did you accidently create Gradle project instead Maven?

Comment: I've created project by hand. Again, build successfull. Nothing inside target folder.

Comment: Actually it works. I was expecting created jar to appear in eclipse. It is inside project folder. Thanks.